# Can I get the data types of an Access table using a query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on a MS Access table but I don't have access to the physical server. Is there a way I can retrieve the column data types using a query?

Answer (score 1):

Just *link* the tables in question from the database running on the server.

Then open the linked tables in design mode, and the fields and their data types will be listed for you.

Comment: He said he doesn't have access to the physical server and the subject line asks for a query. He later states in comments that he only has access through a web service that allows SQL apparently. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: No, except that the specifications for the web service should include the data types. If not, you are left with trial and error, though it should be doable for a single table/service.

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN link should help you.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c8d7b3a6-cd99-4a45-a90b-66bfd6142b35/get-column-name-and-data-types-of-access-tables?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Comment: I have no access to their server but via some trashy webservices. Writing C# code is not an option in my PHP server. Is it possible retrieving datatypes using a query?

Comment: Yes, ultimately that code is just running a query against the system tables. I will create a query for you, but it won't be until later tonight or tomorrow morning. I'm off to my son's baseball game.

Comment: @AllfaridMoralesGarcía re: *"I have no access to their server but via some trashy webservices."* - If so, then I would think the data types of the columns in the underlying tables would be less important than the data types being used by the web services. How are the actual column types going to be useful to you if you cannot directly access the tables themselves?

Comment: Do you send SQL through the web service? It sounds like that isn't the case and you won't be able to query the system tables. Can you provide an example of how you would call the web service?

Comment: The webservice allows me to send an SQL query and returns an array with the results. But I'm trying to make an INSERT but it fails and does not return any error message or log.

Comment: Maybe the service does not allow Insert statements. We need more info on the web service. I'll get you a query you  can try when I get back from lunch.

Comment: I looked into this further and it turns out the system tables aren't very helpful for Data Types. You could get tables names that way, but the only option to get the data types is to use VBA and call the `OpenSchema` method. You'll have to contact the web service developer. On that topic, it's probably not a good idea to have a web service point to a Microsoft Access Database file. It would make more sense to use a server based solution like MySQL or MS SQL Server because those are designed for high traffic.